# How to run one of multiple distinct stages at application startup with javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm starting with javafx and I'm having some trouble understanding how to correctly model the following situation:

Ideally I'd like to have a `main()` method that would somehow allow me to either open a `LoginDialog` or if there's already a user/password combination available on disk, to bypass login and directly show the `MainDialog` to the user.

My main issue is that when I run `Application.launch()` I'm expected to submit an `Application` instance, and when implementing one, I don't have any control over its `Stage` object creation, which creates a catch-22 for me here.

I could create a `LoginScene` and `MainScene` but then I'd have no control for things like the `Stage`'s title, for instance.

What's the usual route to solve this kind of issues with javafx?

Thanks

Comment: You can always get a reference to the stage of your scene: `Stage stage =  (Stage) nodeInScene.getScene().getWindow()`

Comment: I don't understand *"I don't have any control over its `Stage` object creation"*. What's stopping you creating `Stage`s?

Comment: I am given one at startup time instead of being in full control of which stage is being used as the primary stage.

Comment: You're given one as a convenience, but there's no requirement to use it.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. Can I just instantiate others and open them at will without ever using this primaryStage?

Comment: Of course. Why wouldn't you be able to?

Comment: If the API gives me at startup time one stage called "primaryStage" it's tempting to assume it holds some kind of special place for the lifetime of the application. I would never assume it could just be ignored and that one could create other ones that didn't pop up out of this primary one. But indeed what you're saying is true, and that completely solves my problem. Could you put it into your answer so I could give accept your answer?

Comment: Added to answer based on this discussion. FWIW, the only difference between the primary stage and any other stage you create is when you are writing an applet (which, if you're sane, you're not doing, ever). In an applet, the primary stage is embedded in the browser, other stages are shown as standalone windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a single `Application` subclass and put the logic to decide whether you need to show the login screen in the `start()` method (the proper place for startup logic is the aptly-named `start()` method, not the `main` method):

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private boolean loggedIn ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        loggedIn = checkLoginFromDisk();

        while (! loggedIn) {
            FXMLLoader loginLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("path/to/login.fxml"));
            Parent loginRoot = loginLoader.load();
            LoginController loginController = loginLoader.getController();
            Scene loginScene = new Scene(loginRoot);
            primaryStage.setScene(loginScene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Login");
            primaryStage.showAndWait();
            // check login from controller and update loggedIn...
        }

        FXMLLoader mainLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("path/to/main.fxml"));
        Parent mainRoot = mainLoader.load();
        Scene mainScene = new Scene(mainRoot);
        primaryStage.setScene(mainScene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("My Application");
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private boolean checkLoginFromDisk() {
        // ... etc
    }

    // for environments not supporting direct launch of JavaFX:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If you're not using FXML, you just define classes instead of FXML files + controllers for "login" and "main", but the structure stays the same:

```
public class LoginView {

    private final GridPane /* for example */ view ;

    public LoginView() {
        // setup UI, etc...
    }

    public Pane getView() {
        return view ;
    }

    public boolean checkLogin() {
        // etc...
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MainView {

    private BorderPane /* for example */ view ;

    public MainView() {
        // set up UI etc...
    }

    public Pane getView() {
        return view ;
    }
}
```

and your start method then looks like

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    loggedIn = checkLoginFromDisk();

    while (! loggedIn) {
        LoginView loginView = new LoginView();
        Scene loginScene = new Scene(loginView.getView());
        primaryStage.setScene(loginScene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Login");
        primaryStage.showAndWait();
        loggedIn = loginView.checkLogin();
    }
    MainView mainView = new MainView();
    Scene mainScene = new Scene(mainView.getView());
    primaryStage.setScene(mainScene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("My Application");
    primaryStage.sizeToScene();
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Obviously you can refactor this in many different ways (reuse the same login class or fxml instance, use a different stage for the main view, etc etc etc) as you need.

Note that there is no requirement to use the stage passed to the `start()` method. So if you wanted standalone classes to encapsulate the stage containing a login scene and a main scene, you could add the following classes:

```
public class LoginStage extends Stage {

    private final LoginView loginView ;
    public LoginStage() {
        loginView = new LoginView();
        setScene(new Scene(loginView.getView());
        setTitle("Login");
    }

    public boolean checkLogin() {
        return loginView.checkLogin(); 
    }
}
```

and similarly make a `MainStage` class. (In the FXML-based version, the `LoginStage` holds a reference to the `LoginController` and just loads the FXML in the constructor instead of instantiating the `LoginView` class.) Then

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private boolean loggedIn ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage ignored) {
        loggedIn = checkLoginFromDisk();
        while (! loggedIn) {
            LoginStage login = new LoginStage();
            loginStage.showAndWait();
            loggedIn = loginStage.checkLogin();
        }
        new MainStage().show();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi James. The problem with this approach is that I don't have any good way of encapsulating in a self-contained way everything that's related to the Login window and to the Main window. The approach you here describe is similar to what I ended up implementing... which I find worryingly ugly :( I'm finding it hard to believe that such a widely used framework can have such an awkward design, especially when there have been for decades (!) examples of frameworks such as Wpf / Winforms that essentially get this right.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the structure of a JavaFX Application. The login "window" and main "window" are encapsulated in the respective FXML/controller pair, or just a regular class you define (see updated version) if you are not using FXML. The `Application` subclass is solely there for the startup (and shutdown, if you need) of the application; it should contain essentially nothing other than startup logic.

Comment: If you wanted to encapsulate the actual stage as part of the view classes (which imho is an awful idea), you can obviously just ignore the `primaryStage` passed into the start method and retrieve a stage from `LoginView` and `MainView`. I won't post that code though as it's a horrible design (views should not be tightly coupled to the way you want to display them).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be remarkably similar to what I was looking for. It follows jns suggestion.
Not ideal but not terrible:

```
class LoginScene(stage: Stage) extends Scene(new VBox()) {
  val vbox = this.getRoot.asInstanceOf[VBox]

  ...
}

class MainScene(stage: Stage) extends Scene(new VBox()) {
  val vbox = this.getRoot.asInstanceOf[VBox]

  ...
}

class ApplicationStartup extends Application {
  override def start(primaryStage: Stage): Unit = {
    val scene = if (...) new LoginScene(primaryStage) else new MainScene(primaryStage)
    primaryStage.setScene(scene)
    primaryStage.show()
  }
}
```

(code is presented in Scala)

---

Alternatively, as can be seen from the question's comments, one can just ignore the `primaryStage` and create our own ones at will, which it's just what I wanted from the outset:

```
class MainDialog extends Application {
  override def start(primaryStage: Stage): Unit = {
    val newStage = new Stage {
      setTitle("abcdef")
      setScene(new Scene(new Button("Hello World")))
    }
    newStage.show()
  }
}
```